# tufte-handout - dialogue line spacing broken by footnote

Tags: footnotes, tufte, dialogue

I'm using the `dialogue` package and `tufte-handout` class - MWE follows.  The issue I'm experiencing is shown in this image.  After inserting a footnote -- which is actually a citation -- the spacing of paragraphs in the rest of the dialogue is squeezed for the rest of the document.

[image: Adding a footnote breaks paragraphing in dialogue]

Thus, space after speech by *ROBERT* and *MITU* is correct, space after speech by *KAZ* and *JC* is missing.

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=.9cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,textwidth=10.5cm,marginparwidth=8.5cm,marginparsep=.2cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{dialogue}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[mla]{ellipsis}

\parindent = 0em
\setlength\parskip{.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ejemplo.bib}
@phdthesis{kaz-thesis,
  title={Interpretation-driven association in design},
  author={Grace, Kazjon},
  year={2012},
  school={University of Sydney},
  note={Design Lab of the Faculty of Architecture, Design and Planning},
  annote={A computational model of situated analogy making based on the transformation of conceptual spaces.}
}
\end{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Panel session}

\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Robert} Experimental film maker started to do video installations
bringing abstract worlds back into reality. 
%%%
\speak{Mitu} Indie game developer but also a PhD student. 
%%%
\speak{Kaz} I came to CC from design cognition. PhD was in ``How do we
look at a model of analogy making''\cite{kaz-thesis}
\speak{JC} \direct{To \refer{himself}.} This seems very interesting!
\speak{JC} \direct{To \refer{sxe}.}  Oh wait, it's teh broak.
\end{dialogue}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ejemplo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm not a user of either the `tufte` or `dialogue` packages, but a quick look at the `dialogue` documentation (`texdoc dialogue`) shows that `\speak` is defined based on `\item`, with `\setlength\itemsep{\z@ \@plus .5ex}`, so the setting of `\parskip` isn't going to be of much use here.  i think you should also try resetting `\itemsep`.

Comment: thanks very much for your help - by the way I did end up finding a use for `\parskip` <grin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Barbara Beeton's comment:

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\def\cite#1{\setlength\itemsep{\parskip}\oldcite{#1}}
```